# redirecting output of a cmd to a file

Tags: java, ubuntu, cmd

we are trying to re-direct the output of the list to a file using the below cmd(java) in ubuntu, 
Pls let us know if this works or not ?

**Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ls -l >/home/blah blah/new.txt")**

Comment: why not compile->run and see?

Answer (score 3):

No it won't. The '`>`' is part of the shell and as such executing `ls` on its own won't help.

You can:

1. capture the output of the `ls` in Java (capturing the `Process` input stream, as it's confusingly named) and create a file yourself
2. use `"sh -c 'ls whatever > file'"`. The `-c` executes everything following it in a shell, including redirection.